# How to store all column to my database? by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
///some connect to database code here...    
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th width="10">Index</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>numbers</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo"
        <tr>    
            <td><input type='text' name='indexNumber' value='".$row['indexNumber']."' readonly='readonly' size='4' border='0'></input></td>
            <td><textarea name='item' rows='2' readonly='readonly'>".$row['item']."</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name='number' class='txtexample'>".$row['number']."</textarea></td>
        </tr>
            ";}?>
            <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Update"/></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Above is my code, I need update all column of table to my database, if I click submit, just update the last column only.
What wrong in my code? if use javascript, how to solve it?

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
        $index= $_POST["indexNumber"];
        $item1= $_POST["item"];
        $number1= $_POST["number"];
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE `file` SET `item`='$item1' WHERE `indexNumber`='$index';");
    echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Update Successful');window.location='index.php'</script>"; 
?>
```

Above is update.php

Comment: Each field would need to be part of an array ( ie: `<input type='text' name='indexNumber[]' value='x' />` ) and you would need to re-work the code that updates the db ~ though you neglected to share that so we can't help

Comment: @RamRaider, I'm update my code, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array for this.

```
  <tr>    
            <td><input type='text' name='indexNumber[]' value='".$row['indexNumber']."' readonly='readonly' size='4' border='0'></input></td>
            <td><textarea name='item[]' rows='2' readonly='readonly'>".$row['item']."</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name='number[]' class='txtexample'>".$row['number']."</textarea></td>
        </tr>
```

Please check updated script

```
///some connect to database code here...    
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th width="10">Index</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>numbers</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo"
        <tr>    
            <td><input type='text' name='indexNumber[]' value='".$row['indexNumber']."' readonly='readonly' size='4' border='0'></input></td>
            <td><textarea name='item[]' rows='2' readonly='readonly'>".$row['item']."</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name='number[]' class='txtexample'>".$row['number']."</textarea></td>
        </tr>
            ";}?>
            <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Update"/></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: but how to do it if update.php? How to post to database?